# Error while cmake the filament rendering project

Tags: c, opengl, pbr

I was trying to Cmake the google filament project (https://github.com/google/filament ). But I came across the error show below.

[image]

I have followed the steps mention in the Windows build section, but still have the error. 
Is there any other way to build this project ?

Comment: I have installed cygwin as well.  I guess GNU came from that.

Answer (score 0):

In [documentation](https://github.com/google/filament):

Your Linux distribution might default to gcc instead of clang, if that's the case invoke cmake with the following command:

```
$ mkdir out/cmake-release
$ cd out/cmake-release
# Or use a specific version of clang, for instance /usr/bin/clang-7
$ CC=/usr/bin/clang CXX=/usr/bin/clang++ CXXFLAGS=-stdlib=libc++ \
    cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../release/filament ../..
```

So the code seems compilable with GNU.